# Need translation for painting in regards to who the artist is and what it reads in Chinese calligraphy

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image]Watercolor painting with calligraphy script and a red seal it's 7 in x 7 in on paper

Answer (score 3):

**Calligraphy**

> 山茶花

[Camellia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_japonica) flowers

> 建明画於吳都

Painted by Jiànmíng at [Sūzhōu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzhou) City

---

**Seal**

> 朱建明印

Seal of Zhū Jiànmíng

Comment: 苏州的山怎么样？珠穆朗玛峰那么高的？